# User can only login when admin gives permission to log in

Tags: java, jsp, authentication, servlets

Question on JSP and servlet. I have admin and user data in database and when I register as a user and when I try it should not Log In until Admin gives permission to Login..
How do I do. Not getting Any idea..??

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a new user registers mark the user as **InActive** in the DB, only users marked as **Active** in DB can log in inside your application, and also trigger a mail to the admin user saying user X has registered on the portal. On the email sent to the admin provide two buttons **Activate User , Decline User**. If the admin clicks on Activate User change the field from **InActive to Active**.

Now when the user tries to login in the application using his/her userId and password, check the state of the user in DB, if the flag in DB says Active allow user to login, else show a message "***Your verification is in progress and you will be able to access the application post verification***"

**Or if you don't want to trigger email at this point of time, manually update the user as Active for login**